# Laravel: How to automatically inject Object when primary key is a string

Tags: laravel

I have a model as such:

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'some_name';
    protected $primaryKey = 'some_key';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

and I have an API-Controller like this:

```
public function show(Customer $c)
{
    return $c;
}
```

It seems like Laravel can not automatically inject the customer if the key is a string. Or is there a way?

Edit:

This is the API-route:

```
Route::resources([
    ...
    'customer' => CustomerAPIController::class,
    ...
]);
```

Edit2:
Thanks for the detailed answer @Eric Landheer

It works if I rename my variable to $customer as suggested by John Lobo, if you (or Eric) make this an answer I will aprove it. Thank you.
With Erics answer alone I did not understand what to do, even though he outlines the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: it works even if primary key is string .can you show route for that   method .if you are trying other than primary key then  @Eric Landheer answer will help you to solve problem and also route param should match show(Customer $c) variable $c

Comment: change to public function show(Customer $customer)
{
    return $customer;
}

Comment: eric updated answer. if it solved then you can mark answer as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can, take a look at [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name). Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models by `ID`.

To override this behaviour, depending on the definition of your routes, you can change the route as follows:

`Route::get('/customers/{customer:some_field}', [ExampleController::class, 'index'])`;

If you navigate to `/customers/some_value`, it will try and find a match for that `some_field` column in the customers table.

Or, as stated in the docs, you can set the `getRouteKeyName()` in your model if you **always** want to use a different Key for that model. In that case, you can omit the `:some_field` from the route.

---

### **Edit**

As mentioned by @John Lobo, Additionally, you should update the `$c` variable in your `show` function to match the route parameters `$customer`, because Route resources uses singular route parameters.

**CustomerAPIController**

```
public function show(Customer $customer)
{
    return $customer;
}
```

---

**Note:** the value should be unique to ensure the retrieval of only one model. This is often done with a `slug`. Add a `slug` (unique) column to your `Customer` table and model. If the correct, unique slug is provided to the URL, the correct customer will be retrieved.

If you are using multiple models that should be slugged, consider using [this package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) from the Spatie company.

Comment: good to see always trying to provide detailed answer

Comment: kindly update answer .Since op was using Route resources  so it generate singular route param so when injecting variable should match route params so 

public function show(Customer $customer) {
 return $customer; 
}

Comment: @JohnLobo Thanks for pointing that out. Answer updated accordingly!